# Angular clear router path params

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a router config like this.

```
{
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: HomeContentComponent
        },
        {
            path: ':id',
            component: HomeContentComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'home2',
            component: HomeComponent
        },
        {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: '',
            pathMatch: 'full',
        },
    ],
}
```

Everything is working fine. I can navigate to /home/id1 to and the I can read the params in the HomeContentComponent like this.

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.onDestroy)
).subscribe(params => {
  console.log("HERE ARE MY PARAMS ID", params.id);
});
}
```

Now when I logout I clear my local storage and navigate to the login page with

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
```

This works fine. But after the login (maybe from a different user) I navigate back to the home page with

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
```

My problem now is that it automatically has the old id "id1" set from the previous user (route) which I can see on the console output and that the browser automatically loads /home/id1 instead of /home.
But I need to navigate to the /home route without any params.

Is there any way to clear the path params?

Comment: Why dont you use `router.navigate(['/home'])`

Comment: after successful login, you can navigate to home page like
this.router.navigate(['/home']);

https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-7-registration-login-example

Comment: What does clearing localStorage have to do with anything?

Comment: I also tried to navigate with router.navigate(['/home']) but the :id params is still set from the last session. So it redirects automatically to /home/id1. The clearing localStorage part was only to show that I want to clear everything when logout. So that the route path params should also be cleared.

Comment: dont you have errors in console? It seems to me you should have `redirectTo: '/home',` in your routes config, and that this route config is conflicting with the /home route.

Comment: Yes, that was a copy & paste error. I have the redirectTo: '/home'. I don´t have any errors in console. The only thing that I see is in this line of the HomeContentComponent: console.log("HERE ARE MY PARAMS ID", params.id, this.activatedRoute); is that the params.id is set as it was before and the params is set in the activatedRoute object. So it seems to store the last id and navigate to it automatically when navigating with router.navigate() or router.navigateByUrl()

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
router.navigate(['/home'], {replaceUrl: true })`
```

Comment: I already tried this and this didn´t help. The id path params is still set.